# How can I limit my search to answers that I have received?

Tags: support

`user:3437787 [python] is:a` will limit a search to *my* answers, but how can I limit a search to *someone elses answers* to *my* questions?

#### Background:

A while back, I asked a question where someone provided an answer based on list generators. And I just can't seem to find to it. I certainly will, eventually, since I don't have *that* many questions. All the same, I'd like to know if there's a way to limit my search to answers to my questions, but it does not seem to be an easily available option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: you would need to use the data explorer for this

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks for the tip! Would you care to share an example how? Or should I perhaps raise that as an individual question?

Comment: Perhaps you could look for  your question `user:XYZ [python] is:q`, and narrow the search using keyword you remember from your question. And some times using google will simplify the lookup, if you didn't change user name.  '"username" list generator python site:stackoverflow.com' gave me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146507/

Comment: @vestland It's been done [before](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193706/how-to-search-answers-to-my-questions))

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks! Great tip using a limited google search!

Comment: @Nick  I should have known... And I sure looked, but couldn't find it.